# Spring and react integration

Tags: javascript, node.js, spring-mvc, reactjs

I have a problem with integrating reactJS and spring. I know java very well, but I am a beginner in frontend technologies.

I have a spring controller, which simply returns index.html view, which has a script tag with main.js file.

At the beginning it was simple and worked, but then I decided to use react-router component,which requires this :

```
var Router = require('react-router');
```

In the browser I got the following error : ReferenceError: require is not defined

I've made some google reasarch and I found that I need some libraries like gulp, browserify etc ( I am not familiar with these right now ). I found also many examples, but these examples are only js examples where I need to run gulp file etc.

I'd very grateful if somebody gives me a hint what should I learn to be able to integrate it.

Comment: You need to use something to "build" your JS files. Browserify, webpack, gulp are things you can use. You should learn them.

Comment: I think you want to do a client-side bundling with browserify/webpack when compiling your project. You can either do this manually as a terminal command each time or you can add it to whatever packaging framework you are using, like Gradle or Maven. There are a lot of documentation on their sites which will help you.

Comment: I read something about these technologies and I found how to setup a node server and run gulp to wire up browserify etc , but it will run on different port from the one used by tomcat where my java logic is deployed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial on using react-router, where you can find how to add dependencies and build frontend:
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons
You'll also need to configure spring to work as a SPA, which you can do in the controller:
`@RequestMapping(value="/**", method=HTTPMethod.GET)
public String index(){
    return "index"
}`